# Python: stripping charactors from string including \r\n

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a very specific challenge. I am parsing a command line string and need to get rid of everything except a specific pattern of number(s). For example:

```
str = 'abd-256PA\r\n20db'
```

I want to get that number 20! How do I do this? Keep in mind that sometimes the number may be a single digit like `'abc-256\r\n0db'`. And the string will not necessarily contain the `'\r\n'` in it.

I have tried `rstrip`, `lstrip`, `strip`, `[:]` and a few other things without success.

Comment: What is the pattern you are trying to search?

Comment: This site is not about specific *challenges*, but about specific *questions*... Please provide some of the (possibly non-functional) code you have written so far, so we can help you.

Comment: use regular expression (re module)

Comment: What's special about "that number 20"? How do you know, as a human looking at the string, that `20` is the data you want, and not, say, `256`?

Comment: I do not know what that number would be... i was just using the example 20. that is the tricky part. and the only "pattern" that I believe should be constant is the db at the end of a string.

Answer (score 3):

If the number you seek is always at the end of the string, you can fetch it with this kind of regular expression: `([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$`

Example program:

```
import re
print re.search(r'([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$','abd-256PA\r\n20db').group(1)
```

Example output:

```
20
```

Test program:

```
import re

str = ['abd-256PA\r\n20db', 
       'abc-256\r\n0db', 
       'abc-256aa0db',
       'uio1289248282dasd1786ddass',
       '12',
       '2101a123aasdqwqwe']

for x in str:
    print '"%s" >> "%s"' %(x, re.search(r'([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$',x).group(1))
```

Test output:

```
"abd-256PA
20db" >> "20"
"abc-256
0db" >> "0"
"abc-256aa0db" >> "0"
"uio1289248282dasd1786ddass" >> "1786"
"12" >> "12"
"2101a123aasdqwqwe" >> "123"
```

**Explanation by request:**

Python has a regular expression module [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) with a function called [search](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) which tries to find a given regular expression match in the given string.

Basically, this is what `([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$` mean:

- `[0-9]` any number from 0 to 9
- `[0-9]+` 1 or more occurance of any number from 0 to 9
- `[^0-9]` any character BUT numbers from 0 to 9
- `[^0-9]*` a sequence of 0 or more characters where there are no numbers from 0 to 9
- `$` end of the string
- `(...)` capturing group, the stuff we are trying to find
- `([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$` a sequence of 1 or more numbers followed by 0 or more non-numbers followed by the end of the string

The function [re.search](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) takes 2 parameters: a regular expression and a string in which to search for that regular expression. And it returns the object of type [MatchObject](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject). Basically the `group(1)` means "give me the first captured group" (the one in `(...)`).

Comment: @DavidScott612 Look only at the `Example program` part. The rest is testing program which tests different cases. You will be good with the first 2-line program.

Comment: so if I do not know what the string is since I am parsing a command line, do I make that second argument in the re.search a variable? Like print re.search(r'([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$', mystr).group(1). and what is the group(1) function? .... sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @DavidScott612 Added explanation to the answer.

Comment: Cool! I will give this a try and see if it works for me. I need all the help I can get in python since it is not my first language. C++ is.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if your expression always ends with "db", try:

```
import re
d = "abd-256PA\r\n20db"
s = re.search("\d{1,2}db",d)
print d[s.start():s.end()-2]
```

Comment: well I think I just figured it out by using the splitlines() 

like this:
str = "abc123\r\n63db"
t = str.splitlines()
t2 = t.rstrip('db')

Comment: yes, but regex is a regular way, faster and safer than using splitlines()

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
str.replace('\n','').replace('\r','').replace('abc-256','').replace('abd-256','').replace('PA','').replace('db','')
```

It works for the two cases you described.. It just replaces all the pieces of useless information with the empty string.

**updated:**

If you don't know the what the string will be and you only know that after the number you want there is a suffix "db", then you can try this regular expression:

```
import re
regex=re.compile("([0-9]+)db")
str="abd-256PA\r\n20db"
parsed_number = regex.findall(str)[0]
print parsed_number
```

Comment: keep in mind that I do not know what the string will be. it is blind to me.